# R Mixed design ANOVA with aov, Interpretation of results

Tags: r, anova, interpretation

I'm struggling with interpreting the output from R for a mixed-design ANOVA.

The code I used is the following:

Calculate mixed ANOVA (WS factor=variable (trust benevolence/trust competence), BS factor=condition (distant future/near future))

```
aov_trust_condition = aov(value ~ Condition*variable + Error(id/variable), data=data3_long)
summary(aov_trust_condition)
```

Can you tell me, if the Within-Subjects-Factor and the Between-Subjects-Factor are at the right position?

Then I get the following output:

```
Error: id
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Condition   1    0.7  0.7443   0.508  0.477
Residuals 279  409.2  1.4665               

Error: id:variable
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
variable             1   13.5  13.468   9.443 0.00233 **
Condition:variable   1    0.1   0.120   0.084 0.77183   
Residuals          279  397.9   1.426                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would interpret the results like that:

*Error: id Condition: Pr= 0,477* -> Difference between the two Conditions distant future and near future is not significant.

*Error: id:variable Variable: Pr= 0,00233* -> Significant difference between trust benevolence and trust competence.

*Error: id:variable Condition:variable: Pr= 0,77183* -> No significant difference between groups splitted up by Condition and variable.

Is this interpretation correct or am I making a mistake?